# Grails - Limit an IP Address' Upload Rate

Tags: grails, upload, ip-address

I am creating a Grails application and I'm trying to figure out the best way to prevent a user from spamming posts on my server. I have an infinite number of forms where they can leave comments. I don't want them to have the ability to send a million comments. I know there exists a way to mock "server lag" so that the data rate slows down. Within the grails framework, is there a good way to set the maximum post size limit/rate?

I tried looking into any possibility of setting this via the tomcat properties but I wasn't having too much luck there with my own research.

Thanks much!!!

Comment: When you say limit the size/rate of a post, is that an HTTP post? For any kind of data or just file uploads or something completely different?

Comment: just a general post of a text field, yeah.

Comment: Are your users logged in and have a session? I ask because it would be easy enough to write a filter that limits their ability to post within a time frame based on the last time they posted something.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you want to restrict the size of a post which is provided by the user. If yes, then you can add the [`maxSize`](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.x/ref/Constraints/maxSize.html) constraint in the domain class (or any command object if it is used).

If you are looking to prevent form re-submission then you can use [formTokens](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.4/guide/single.html#formtokens) to prevent a duplicate submission.

Comment: I don't want them to be able to do a million small posts either. So I just want to limit the rate at which they can throw data on my server.

Comment: Why would you allow them to repost in the view once they have posted? You can just disable the form submission altogether.